# ¿Cómo puedo hacer match con una consulta sobre un valor dividido? - Elasticsearch

Tags: json, indices

Tengo un índice en *Elasticsearch v2.4.1*, en el cual almaceno valores desde un *feed* en JSON. Algunas veces recibo valores con todos los caracteres, separados con espacio, como por ejemplo:

```
"titulo" : "E l a ñ o q u e e l m e r c a d o d e j ó d e a s u s t a r"
```

No siempre sucede, alrededor del `%15` de las entradas presentan este problema. Esto impide que consultas como:

```
localhost:9200/indice/_search?q=titulo:mercado
```

Hagan match al documento anterior.

Pienso que este problema se soluciona con algún tipo de *CharFilter*, pensé que con el de *N-Grams*, pero no es lo que busco. Sé que es algo complejo, puesto que implica en algún nivel el reconocimiento (o índice) del lenguaje, tal vez lidiar con ambigüedades, entre otros.

Comment: si eliminas los espacios?